# Circuit not amplifying signal from transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, filter

I'm using the following circuit to produce white noise. I'm applying 12V DC from a power supply. But my noise is **very low** - not at all amplified! I was expecting at least 100mV Vpp, but it's only about consistent 10mV Vpp.

From what I've seen from [this](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/white-noise-generator-circuit-that-will-work-down-to-7vdc.153153/) link and [this](https://www.eeweb.com/simple-white-noise-generator/) link I suppose it should be giving more amplification at the output than what I'm getting.

Is this the normal behavior of the circuit or am I missing something? What could I do to amplify the signal at the output without introducing op-amps (I was hoping T2 would gain a lot more)?

Thank you a lot!

I'm using 2N3904. But also tried with BC547 and BC3337. I also tried changing R1 to 48k ohms, with no result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the DC voltage level is at the collector of T2. Ideally, you want this to be about 6 volts. Relying on the breakdown of T1 to bias T2 the right amount is usually quite problematic. There are better ways.

Comment: Before we get into any whys or wherefores -- I see you expected 100mV peak to peak.  But -- over what frequency range?  What transistors are you using, and what did the original article call out?  Are you using bandlimiting on the scope, and is it different from what the original article used?

Comment: I'm sorry @TimWescott, you are right. I edited the question to include the transistors I've tried.

Comment: @Andyaka The voltage at the collector of T2 is around 9.5V. I put a resistor of 1M ohm instead of 4.7k ohm to bring it down but didn't do any effect to the output (still around 10mV Vpp)

Comment: 9.5 volts is OK on a 12 volt supply. What's the scope show (noise wise) on the base of T2 compared to the proper output?

Comment: The capacitance of C3 is so small that it cuts 1600Hz -3dB and lower frequencies at -6dB per octave. Calculate capacitors for 20Hz, use 10uF or 22uF instead for audio. The current in the first transistor is much too low. Bias it separately with more current then capacitor-couple the noise to the second transistor that has its own correct biasing. Each first transistor will have its own breakdown voltage and noise level.

Comment: @Audioguru are you sure you meant C3? Or C2?

Comment: @Andyaka both signals look alike. It looks like the is "offseting" the noise to 0V, which makes sense to me since its a high-pass filter. But in terms of amplitude of the signal they are pretty much alike

Comment: R3 and C3 have a cutoff frequency of 1600Hz. R4 and C2 have a cutoff frequency of 16Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The voltage at the collector of T2 is around 9.5V.

OK, so there's about 0.5mA flowing through Q2, and its emitter is at 0.5V. Q1's B-E Zener diode has about 12V-(0.5V+0.65V)=11V across it. That should be enough, but go for a 15V supply until it works better. It can't hurt.

Not all transistors will be equally noisy. 2N2222 was my go-to part for Zener noise generation. Maybe try that for Q1. An order of magnitude range in noise amplitude is normal between various types of transistors. I'd get one of those cheap transistor kits, and try various PNP and NPN types in reverse B-E breakdown. You'll see that some of them are much noisier than others.

I'd say the circuit works just fine with 10mV output noise amplitude. That's just what you get with the particular transistors you tried.

C2-R4 is not necessary for measurements. Remove those, add an emitter follower loaded with 33k, then hook that emitter up directly to a 10x scope probe, AC coupled channel.

Make sure the PicoScope is aware of the 10x probe you're using.